# Tweets from a particular hashtag and posted from a particular app

Tags: ios, xcode, tweets

I want to get tweets from a particular hashtag AND tweeted from a particular app only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i found, there is no single line code you can put.
First i retrieved tweets according to the hashtag using,

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hashtag&rpp=20&result_type=mixed&page=1

Then i filtered the response using the parameter "source" which contains the app name - using rangeOfString:.

I tried putting both in the url, but it did not work out.
Hope this helps someone.